# If, elif > too many conditions

Tags: python, django

I have here several conditions and 'sub-conditions'. It looks quite messy and I wonder if you know a better way to write this code here?

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.instance

    # Conditions
    if instance.available_amount <= instance.redeemed_amount:
        instance.status = Discount.STATUS_NO_MORE_LEFT
    elif instance.valid_until <= timezone.now():
        instance.status = Discount.STATUS_EXPIRED

    # Conditions to set active
    elif instance.status == Discount.STATUS_NO_MORE_LEFT:
        if instance.available_amount > instance.redeemed_amount:
            instance.status = Discount.STATUS_ACTIVE
    elif instance.status == Discount.STATUS_EXPIRED:
        if instance.valid_until > timezone.now():
            instance.status = Discount.STATUS_ACTIVE
```

Comment: It's not clear here whether there is a default value for `status` and/or whether that value might be set to anything, nothing, or some arbitrary value in `form.instance`. Partially because of that, I'm also not sure if you mean for the first conditional in that second block to be `elif` and not a new `if`.

Answer (score -2):

I have 2 suggestions:

Use the `and` keyword and split your conditions over 2 lines for readability:

```
elif (instance.status == Discount.STATUS_NO_MORE_LEFT
      and instance.available_amount > instance.redeemed_amount):
    instance.status = Discount.STATUS_ACTIVE
elif (instance.status == Discount.STATUS_EXPIRED 
      and instance.valid_until > timezone.now()):
    instance.status = Discount.STATUS_ACTIVE
```

Use a shorter variable name to reduce line length (and in turn ‘messiness’):

```
inst= form.instance
obj = form.instance
x = form.instance
# the latter is shorter but too vague
```

Comment: _Use a shorter variable name to reduce line length (and in turn ‘messiness’)..._ Cutting 'ance' off of 'instance' saves four characters for no meaningful improvement. 'obj' makes generic enough to get confusing if the code becomes more complex later on. Messiness has nothing to do with variable name length, and in fact, a longer name (within reason) can be a good thing. Your combined conditionals also change the meaning of those `elifs`, as the original code does not depend on `instance.available_amount` when checking `instance.status`, so this is simply incorrect.